# Is it possible to mark every email sent from Gmail (eventually if with a specific label) as unread + MOVE TO INBOX

Tags: gmail

As per the title?

**Is it possible to mark every email sent from Gmail (eventually if with a specific label) as unread + MOVE TO INBOX?**

I looked into several options (fitlers, set labels at sending time..) but none of this works to:

- set as unread
- move to inbox

**automatically**.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to create a filter on outgoing messages with a particular label? I'm reasonably sure you can't do this with a filter, since sent messages don't generally get added to the inbox and filters can only "skip" the inbox on incoming messages. Since sent messages aren't incoming, and you can't have a filter explicitly add the special inbox label, that won't work.

Comment: you got my request right. I'm not strict about going through the filter approach, but I would like to have emails I sent to go to Inbox folder. any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> **in:all**

In the search box

Alternatively select *All mail* from your labels list, you may have to click the drop down triangle in "More..." To make it visible.

This search will not include trashed emails, if you want to include them first untrash them or use the search

> **in:all AND is:trashed**

tip: you can use any search directives (what you would type on the search box) directly on the "has the words:" field, and it will override any selections made on the filter creation form! just test the search and click "create filter with this search",  your arbitrarily complex search directive will generate a filter.

Comment: the idea seems good but how do I use in:all to define a filter?

Comment: right. it gets counter-intuitive right here. its kind of a monkeypatch from google i guess until they find a better way to flow it into the filter interface. in:a

Comment: *in:all* is active when you select *"all mail"* on the filter dialog drop-down (its the very first item) add is:trashed to the "has the words:" box. in fact you can cram the whole search directive on the "has the words:" box and it will override any selections you made on the form previously! (undocumented feature?)